# Project settings in Gitlab

Tags: settings, project, gitlab

Where now "Project settings" in Gitlab?
How delete repository? And change "Visibility Level" repository? And rename project?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below the "Audit Events" item in the menu you have pulled down in the picture, you should see an option called "Edit Project" that will allow you to do everything you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

As per 2017

For Project name;
In the GitLab project page, left panel --> Settings --> General --> General project settings --> Expand

For the visibility level;
In the GitLab project page, left panel --> Settings --> General --> Permissions --> Expand

Answer (score 0):

When you rename your project, through its settings page, make sure to *not* include leading or trailing special character in the new name:

See [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#special-characters-not-permitted-in-new-project-names) (March 2022)

> ### Special characters not permitted in new project names
>
> Project and Group names that have a leading or trailing special character breaks the container registry.
>
> As of this release, you can no longer use special characters as the first or last characters of **new** project or group names.
> You can still use special characters in any other part in the name.
>
> This ensures proper functionality within all stages at GitLab, and enhances the experience of our single platform tool.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#create-a-blank-project) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/349047).